# Adding up negative numbers in a Python Table

Tags: python

I have this list:

```
my_list = [7, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1, -2, -3, -5, -7]
```

and then I proceeded to add up the negative numbers using this code:

```
mynb = 0
i = 0
while True:
    i += 1
    if my_list[i] <= 0 and i <= len(my_list):
        mynb += my_list[i]
    print(mynb)
    if i > 100:  # avoid infinite loop
        break
```

and I got this error

> `IndexError: list index out of range`

I have tried fixing this error but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: i < len(my_list) because Python lists are indexed from `0` to `len(l) - 1` since the list is of length `len(l)`. Moreover, a `while` doesn't seem to be the good solution. An easier way, not to deal with index problems, would be `for i in range(len(ny_list))` then work with it.

Comment: This should work: `sum(i for i in my_list if i < 0)`

Comment: You error is caused because your loop never terminates, so you keep on incrementing `i` until it's bigger than the number of items in your list.

Comment: To "fix" your code, you can reverse the order of your conditional and change the `<=` to `<`. However this will lead to an infinite loop because of the `while True:`

Answer (score 2):

`sum(x for x in l if x < 0)` will achieve your purpose.
It goes through all elements in your list, and adds them under your condition.
The `sum` is self explanatory. The expression between `()` is called a generator, which you can use to loop efficiently.

Comment: You can write `sum(x for x in l if x <= 0)` too, as generator expressions require only one set of parenthesis around them.

Comment: `x < 0`. One character less. :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem arises from having your if conditional check your value before checking the length of the list you are indexing.

```
mylist[i] <= 0
```

evaluates before

```
i <= len(mylist)
```

causing your error.

Better than doing a while loop would be to do:

```
for item in my_list:
    if item <= 0:
        mynb += item
```

Comment: Also `i<= len(mylist)` should be `i < len(mylist)`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use while cycle:

```
while True:
    i += 1
    if i < len(my_list):
        if my_list[i] <= 0:
            mynb += my_list[i]
    else:
        break
```